# How to write a procedure to get my desired output?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Present data:

```
A              VALID_FROM    VALID_TO
------------   -----------   -----------
ARN-1          01-APR-2015   31-DEC-9999
ARN-1          01-MAY-2015   31-DEC-9999
ARN-1          01-JUN-2015   31-DEC-9999
```

Required output:

```
A              VALID_FROM    VALID_TO
------------   -----------   -----------
ARN-1          01-APR-2015   30-APR-2015
ARN-1          01-MAY-2015   31-MAY-2015
ARN-1          01-JUN-2015   31-DEC-9999
```

How can I write an Oracle PL/SQL procedure to get this output?

Comment: You haven't explained what you are trying to do or the logic for how to set the `valid_to` date. Always one day before the start of the next `valid_from`? What if there is a gap that isn't a month (a row missing, or not starting on the 1st)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of **PL/SQL**, you could do it in pure **SQL**.

You need **LAST_DAY** function to get the last day of that month for the date value in `VALID_FROM` column. **ROW_NUMBER** is just to handle the max date case where you need the magic date `31-DEC-9999`.

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'ARN-1' A, DATE '2015-04-01' VALID_FROM, DATE '9999-12-31' VALID_TO FROM dual
  3  UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'ARN-1' A, DATE '2015-05-01' VALID_FROM, DATE '9999-12-31' VALID_TO FROM dual
  5  UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'ARN-1' A, DATE '2015-06-01' VALID_FROM, DATE '9999-12-31' VALID_TO FROM dual
  7  UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 'ARN-1' A, DATE '2015-07-01' VALID_FROM, DATE '9999-12-31' VALID_TO FROM dual
  9  )
 10  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
 11  SELECT a,
 12    valid_from,
 13    CASE
 14      WHEN rn = 1
 15      THEN DATE '9999-12-31'
 16      ELSE valid_to
 17    END valid_to
 18  FROM
 19    (SELECT A,
 20      valid_from,
 21      row_number() OVER(ORDER BY valid_from DESC) rn,
 22      last_day(valid_from) valid_to
 23    FROM sample_data
 24    )
 25  ORDER BY valid_from;

A     VALID_FROM  VALID_TO
----- ----------- -----------
ARN-1 01-APR-2015 30-APR-2015
ARN-1 01-MAY-2015 31-MAY-2015
ARN-1 01-JUN-2015 30-JUN-2015
ARN-1 01-JUL-2015 31-DEC-9999

SQL>
```

Comment: The OP seems to want the last defined period to keep the magic-value end-date. Though it isn't exactly clear...

Comment: I thought it is a typo, but if OP wants it that way then it would need a windowing function. I see other answers using LAG/LEAD, but I think last_day is more appropriate, just that the max valid_from should have the magic date.

Comment: Unless there's a gap in the records or they don't always start on the 1st. But unclear if that can happen or what the output should be if it does. If the `valid_from` dates are the 1st of every month then yes, just not sure that can be safely assumed from the limited info *8-)

Comment: Yes, your are right. As of current scope of question, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this:

```
insert into tableB
select A,
       valid_from,
       nvl(lead(valid_from)  over (partition by a order by valid_from asc) -1, valid_to)
from tableA
```

This inserts all the rows in the second table, evaluating for each row the end of validity, if exists; if it does not exist, it uses the end date already present on the row.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( A, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO ) AS
SELECT 'ARN-1', DATE '2015-04-01', DATE '9999-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ARN-1', DATE '2015-05-01', DATE '9999-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ARN-1', DATE '2015-06-01', DATE '9999-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

**Update**:

```
UPDATE table_name t
SET valid_to = ( SELECT NVL( next_valid_from, valid_to )
                 FROM   (
                   SELECT a,
                          valid_from,
                          LEAD( valid_from ) OVER ( PARTITION BY a ORDER BY valid_from )
                            - INTERVAL '1' SECOND -- Change to DAY if you prefer
                            AS next_valid_from,
                          valid_to
                   FROM   table_name
                 ) n
                 WHERE  t.a = n.a
                 AND    t.valid_from = n.valid_from
               );
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;

A     VALID_FROM            VALID_TO            
----- --------------------- ---------------------
ARN-1 2015-04-01 00:00:00   2015-04-30 23:59:59   
ARN-1 2015-05-01 00:00:00   2015-05-31 23:59:59   
ARN-1 2015-06-01 00:00:00   9999-12-31 00:00:00
```